# No signature of method: java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types

Tags: java, groovy

I am getting this error msg in my Eclipse with latest Groovy installed.

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [d/M/yyyy H:m:s, 28/09/2010 16:02:43]
Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String), wait(), clone(), grep(), any(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyGuardsFiltersAndSignatures.unwrap(IndyGuardsFiltersAndSignatures.java:175)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:234)
    at GroovyLearn.main(GroovyLearn.groovy:222)

String theDate = "28/09/2010 16:02:43";
def newdate = new Date().parse("d/M/yyyy H:m:s", theDate);
```

Expected Result: `Tue Sep 28 16:02:43 CEST 2010`

Actual Result: got error that parse does not work properly

Comment: `Date.parse()` accepts one `String` argument but you are trying to pass 2...

Comment: Did you run as GroovyScript or as Java Application? This should work in Groovy: https://github.com/apache/groovy/search?q=%22Date.parse%22&unscoped_q=%22Date.parse%22

Comment: @Zephyr - i am passing 1 string - tested it outside from eclipse and it worked just fine, maybe i have wrong version of this

Comment: @ndueck - https://i.imgur.com/vuw9Mow.png check this - parse function is crossed, i think problem is in eclipse now, because i tested it in groovyConsole and it worked just fine - i tested both options, non of them worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parse` is a static method on `Date`

Instead of

```
def newdate = new Date().parse("d/M/yyyy H:m:s", theDate)
```

You need to do

```
def newdate = Date.parse("d/M/yyyy H:m:s", theDate)
```